# Permutation test based in the Wilcoxon test

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

I am testing the statistical significance of 60 strong correlated quantitative variables in 2 groups, with small sample size, non normality and presence of outliers.
I have implemented a permutation test based in the t-test statistic for deal correctly the correlation structure of the variables; but I think this permutation test could be also based in the statistic of the nonparametric Wilcoxon test, due to the presence of the outliers. Is it correct?

Comment: The Wilcoxon test is a permutation test already. It computes the permutation distribution of (a monotonic function of) a t-test on the ranks. Your permutation test based off a t- is already nonparametric; perhaps your concern is to make it more robust to outliers rather than to make it nonparametric. What are the response values measuring?

Comment: The data are expression of peptides in proteins. They are normalized with similar techniques of genetic expression data, but the results are very inestable and generate outliers.

Comment: Are these values a measurement or a count or some other thing?

Comment: There are a measurement. The problema is your comment: "the Wilcoxon test is a permutation test", but I want to use as basic statistic is my permutation test because I want to treat the correlation structure between the variables.

Comment: (I am completely in favor of doing permutation tests with the most suitable statistic for your problem; that comment was simply clarifying that the Wilcoxon isn't distinct from permutation tests.) If you're looking for robustness to outliers, simply construct a permutation statistic that has the robustness properties you want, while retaining the other properties you need it to have.