How do I calculate the p-value for two success rates where one of the test sets is a subset of the other?
I know questions like this have been asked a hundred times but unfortunately I'm not smart enough to figure out which answer applies to my problem.
For context: I have an image classification model that has an accuracy of 95.89% on a test set. Now, unfortunately some of the test set has been seen during training. What I want to know is whether the model benefitted from that making the result misleading. What I did to test that is create a subset of the test set with only images that the model has never seen, so an uncontaminated test set. On that the model has an accuracy of 95.32%, so as expected the model performed worse, but I don't know whether that has to do with the contamination or whether the subset is just unlucky. So I thought my Null Hypothesis would be that the contamination has no impact on the performance of the model. And now I have to figure out how high the probability is for a random subset of that size to perform the way that it did. I have the set sizes of course and could provide them but I honestly just want pointers on what my scenario is called and which methods there are. I can do the calculations myself.
I found a so called R-Test, which kind of sounds like what I want but I'm not sure because the two datasets aren't independent of one another. One contains the entirety of the other one.
I also have trained three architecturally equivalent models (as is good practice in ml for reproducibility) so I actually have three very similar accuracies for each set and could approximate a standard deviation from that for each, but I don't know if and how to weave that in.
As I said - I'd be satisfied with the correct terms to look for or a link, the rest I can figure out myself.

Many posts on site discuss this issue, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79056/how-to-compare-two-samples-of-frequencies-with-categorical-x-values-where-one-is/

I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of this site! Had a look around now, thanks for the link.
Making the subsets non-overlapping seems very obvious in hindsight. But I'm not sure about using a chi-squared test. The thing is from my 3 runs I know that the standard deviation is extremely low and that the difference to the subset is therefore relatively unlikely. On the other hand the smaller size of the subset would increase the standard deviation, right? But the chi-squared test takes neither a stdd nor a sample size into account. So either my intuition is completely off or that is not what I need.

The chi-squared test is based on counts. I presumed your "percentage accuracy" figures were count proportions; it might be best to give an explicit formula in the question. The same argument (use non-overlapping samples) applies to tests of means, for example (and there are posts that discuss that case too), so the point being made at the link is the same for other statistics.

Let $N$ be the size of the complete test set and $n$ the size of the subset. We assume that the successful classification of the images is a set of $N$ independent Bernoulli variables. The null hypothesis states that all these Bernoulli variables have the same parameter $p.$ The alternative hypothesis states that the variables in the subset are identically distributed with parameter $p'<p.$
If $N$ is sufficiently large (say, $100$ or more) and much larger than $n$ it is acceptable to estimate $p=0.9589$ and then you need to compute the probability that a binomial variable with parameters $n$ and $p$ evaluates lower than $0.9532\times n.$
$$P(B(n,p)\leq x)=\sum_{i=0}^x{n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$
Note that we do not need to round down $x=0.9532\times n$ because it is already an integer, namely, the number of successes on the subset.
If that probability is less than, say $5$ percent, you can reject the null hypothesis.
